# Shared app ownership between multiple StackApps users

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to have the ability to allow multiple SA users to share ownership over one application. Is this something coming down the line?

Comment: I'd totally ask this on http://meta.stackapps.com, but it's not online yet. :-)

Comment: I would like this as well.